# Mobile subcategory dropdown on mobile theme

Tags: category, css, menu, mobile

we are making mobile layout for our web site, but we don't know how to edit the subcategory dropdown: which code to add or change?

http://transmog.net/iphone-simulator/mobile-web-browser-emulator-for-iphone-5.php?u=http://test.arredodesignonline.com/it/tavoli-sedie.html

(the dropdown that starts with the word "sedie")

Comment: http://www.demacmedia.com/design-user-experience/magento-mobile-off-canvas-navigation-menu/ this should give you the steps of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: we are talking about the dropdown that starts with the word "sedie", which is not working for the moment... It should change the product sub-category

Comment: the category you are talking about, are you sure is there any sub category assigned?

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't know what is exactly what you wanna do but in this template is where the navigation is render

```
/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/topmenu.phtml
```

and in this php file is where loads the items and put the classes to each item

```
/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Topmenu.php
```

Hope it helps you to go in the right direction.

Comment: Please don't just start editing these files. If you need to do something to the block or templates at least create a separate module with rewrites that inherit the class and pull the template changes into your custom theme.